# regex to match on three leading and ending single quotes

Tags: java, regex

I'm having issues getting the correct syntax for my java regex below.  I would just like to search a String to see if it contains a chunk of text that starts with three single quotes and ends with three single quotes but that can have other text in front and in back of it.  Anything UTF-8 character can exist between the three single quotes.  Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

```
          String value="'''<html><head><title>Hello World</title></head><body><div>text</div></body></html>'''";
          Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'''[\\w*]'''");
          Matcher m = p.matcher(value);
          if(m.find()){
              System.out.println("''' found");
          }else{
              System.out.println("''' not found");
          }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any ideas where I've gone wrong?

There are 2 things wrong with your regular expression:

1. You are trying to place the `*` quantifier within the character class while it should be placed outside.
2. You are trying to use the word character (\w) predefined character class for matching characters such as <,>,/ while it will only match `[a-zA-Z_0-9]`. If you want to match any character use the `.` (any character)

Changing the regular expression to `Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'''.*'''");` should make the code provided in your question to work.

Patterns suggested in other answers will also provide a solution.

Answer (score 3):

Use:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile(".*'{3}.*'{3}$");
```

`.*` denotes any character multiple times (optional)

`'{3}` denotes 3 single quotes

`.*` denotes any character multiple times (optional)

`'{3}` denotes 3 single quotes

`$` denotes end of String

Comment: The leading ^ is not needed. In the example the string starts with three quotes, but this is not stated in the question: "contains three single quotes and ends with three single quotes"

Comment: @rmuller so technically the first 3 single quotes would be optional, since the string would need to contain three single quotes at the end

Comment: @KevinBowersox - the string could have other text before and after the  three single quotes.

Comment: @c12 Bust must the String contain a total of 6 single quotes, 3 somewhere in the string and three at the end? Or could three single quotes at the end satisfy your criteria?

Comment: @KevinBowersox - correct it must contain 3 somewhere and 3 to end it.  so this is a better example String test="this is my string of '''<html>.....</html>''' some end text here"; The String could also start with ''' and end with ''' and not have any other text. So I guess a regex that searches for three ' with text in between then three more '

Comment: String test="text'''text'''text"; didn't match the pattern as it should

Comment: @c12 please update your question to be in line with the clarifications just discussed

Comment: @c12 But that fails the test, it doesn't contain 3 single quotes at the end of the string

Answer (score 1):

Try with this regex :

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("'{3}.*'{3}$");
```

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that you want to capture the String data between the single quotes.
In that case, you are using the wrong parentheses (you use `[]` instead of `()`). Furthermore, I guess you want to use a `\w*` to allow all possible content. However, `\w` stands for "word characters", which ususally only covers `[A-Za-z0-9_]`, meaning that it does *not* cover your html characters.

To clarify: a shorthand character class such as `\w` should *not* appear inside of the `[]` brackets. `\w*` is the same as `[A-Za-z0-9_]*`, which also demonstrates that your asterisk quantifier (`*`) comes *after* the character class, not inside of it.

A usable form of your regex would then be `Pattern.compile("'''(\\w*)'''");`. However, that does not cover html characters such as `<`.

Try to use `Pattern.compile("'''(.*)'''");`, as the `.` stands for "all characters".

By using the parentheses (in this case, these form a capture group), you can access the string matched by this group using `m.group(1)` after your call to `m.find()`.